# Problem in loading an as2 movie inside as3 movie

Tags: actionscript, action

My scenario is that i have host swf that is of as3 and need to load an as2 movie into it.Now I need to control the as2 movie for keeping the host as3 swf and the as2 swf in sync. To do that I am using a local connection. But the problem i'm facing is that, when as2 loaded via as3 movie, I don't see as2 events being fired. For example, I kept a trace in onEnterFrame in as2 movie. Stand-alone I could see the traces. But when loaded from as3 movie, I could not see any of them.

I have 3 movie clips

1. Loader as3 movie
2. AS2 wrapper movie (Generic for all AS2 movies that will have local connection code.
   this will get msgs from as3 and internally does what ever we wanted)
3. the actual as2 movie to be loaded into as3

can anyone throw some light on this???

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading (3) into the SWF? There's a problem with AMV1Movie's (AS2 SWFs loaded into AS3 SWFs are created as AMV1Movie objects) loading of additional movies: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/AVM1Movie.html

Have you tried something like SWFBridge: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/swfbridge_easie.html?

Comment: I tried using LocalConnection object to communicate ( similar to SWF bridge ). If I have trace in onEnterFrame of maintimeline of as2 movie, I could see that when loaded into as3. But I have a movieclip on as2 movie maintimeline and onEnterFrame on that particular movieclip, I dont see trace messages

Comment: AS2 - maintimeline - onEnterFrame - traces appear                  AS2 - maintimeline - child movieclip - onEnterFrame - traces dont appear

Comment: are the events themselves not working, or is it just that you're not receiving any traces messages?